# ¿Sintaxis para quitar el privilegio a un usuario de un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

En la línea de comandos de MySQL le di permiso a un usuario para acceder a un procedimiento almacenado (Stored procedure) con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE Acervo_bibliografico.InsertarDatoUsuario 
              TO 'Brandon_Padilla'@'localhost';
```

Ahora deseo quitarle el privilegio pero no sé qué sintaxis utilizar. ¿Cómo se haría?

La base de datos es: `Acervo_bibliografico` y el procedimiento almacenado es `InsertarDatoUsuario`.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a los que vieron mi pregunta, estuve insertando diversas combinaciones en la línea de comandos y al final encontré la respuesta, la sintaxis es:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE InsertarDatoUsuario FROM 'Brandon_Padilla'@'localhost';
```

Saludos y Gracias!!